# How to loop through array elements to create multiple insert queries

Tags: php, arrays, insert, foreach

I have a $_POST array which currently takes the following form:

```
 ["Area"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(5) "Title" 
    [1]=> string(5) "Title" 
    } 
 ["Issue"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "111" 
    [1]=> string(7) "2222222" 
    } 
 ["Elevation"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "11111111" 
    [1]=> string(7) "2222222" 
    } 
 ["Fix"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "11111111" 
    [1]=> string(6) "222222" 
    } 
 ["ExpectFee"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "11111111" 
    [1]=> string(5) "22222" 
    } 
 ["Outlay"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(9) "111111111" 
    [1]=> string(9) "222222222" 
    } 
 ["ExpctTime"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(9) "111111111" 
    [1]=> string(11) "22222222222" 
 } 
 ["Checkbox"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(12) "111111111111" 
    [1]=> string(11) "22222222222" 
    }
```

I am currently looping through it like this...

```
 if ($_POST['OthProb']['Issue'] != '') {
       $table = 'tbl_customproblems';
       $kv = array();

            foreach ($_POST['OthProb'] as $array) {
                foreach ($array as $value) {
                    $kv[] = "'".$value."'";

            }
            $string = "INSERT INTO $table (AccountID, myID, Area, Issue, Elevation, Fix, ExpectFee, Outlay, ExpctTime, Checkbox) VALUES ('$_POST[AccountID]', '$_POST[myID]', ".join(", ", $kv).")";     
        }

} else {
  $string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}

$sql = $DBH->prepare($string);
$sql->execute();
```

Which almost works! It produces this...

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_customproblems (AccountID, PropertyID, Area, Issue, Elevation, Fix, ExpectFee, Outlay, ExpctTime, WHCheckbox) VALUES ('81', '81', 'Title', 'Title', '111', '2222222', '11111111', '2222222', '11111111', '222222', '11111111', '22222', '111111111', '222222222', '111111111', '22222222222', '111111111111', '22222222222')"
```

How do I amend my loop to produce seperate inserts, one for each row being passed.

Comment: you're misusing `prepare()`. `$_POST` values should go into `execute()`. And what's up with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` ? That's not a SQL query :)

Comment: consider me to be completely self taught. Can you provide a link to clarify please, cos I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: Take a look at the examples from [`PDO:prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) docs

Comment: I have to admit, I've tried to copy and amend something that I've already got in place and functioning correctly for a different type of array. Have only been programming for a few months, am completely self taught and still have some way to go before  I get my head round everything.

Comment: Im definitely getting the expected values, I just don't know what I'm doing with them :P, 'OthProb' is like a box that contains an load of folders (column names) and their associated files (values). I'm passing an awful lot of stuff so I've do this as I can then use the box name to perform actions on its contents.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be something like this:

```
if ($_POST['OthProb']['Issue'] != '') {
$table = 'tbl_customproblems';
$string = 'INSERT INTO $table (AccountID, myID, Area, Issue, Elevation, Fix, ExpectFee, Outlay, ExpctTime, Checkbox) VALUES (:AccountID, :myID, :Area, :Issue, :Elevation, :Fix, :ExpectFee, :Outlay, :ExpctTime, :Checkbox)';

$sql = $DBH->prepare($string);

$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['OthProb'] as $array) {

    $sql->bindParam(':AccountID', $_POST['AccountID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':myID', $_POST['myID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':Area', $array['area'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR); //it can also be PDO::PARAM_STR

        $sql->execute();
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I didn't bind all params so you have to do that your self, I hope you get the idea of a prepare statement by this example.

At a prepare statement you use `PDO::PARAM_INT` when you want a integer and you will be using `PDO::PARAM_STR` for strings. When you are not sure if it is a integer or a string you better use `PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: Thanks for explaining how bound variables work, I feel a bit clearer on that now, but that code I isn't looping through the array properly and is doing 8 insert statements (one for each column in the array) I just want to loop through the first row, do an insert, then loop through the second row, do an insert.

Answer (score 0):

I got it in the end using the following code, its probably hacky to the max and I intend to refine it in the future but it works.

```
if ($_POST['OthProb']['Issue'] != '') {
       $kv = array();
       // This will help control the array index
       $i = 0;
       // count the number of records in the array
       $count = count($_POST['OthProb']['Area']);
       $table = 'tbl_customproblems';

       // Loop through each index - stop before we reach the value of count.
       for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
           // Catch the data
           foreach ($_POST['OthProb'] as $value) {
                    $kv[] = "'".$value[$i]."'";       
            }
        // Do the insert!
        $string = "INSERT INTO $table (AccountID, PropertyID, Area, Issue, Elevation, Fix, ExpectFee, Outlay, ExpctTime, Checkbox) VALUES ('$_POST[AccountID]', '$_POST[PropertyID]', ".join(", ", $kv).") ";
        $sql = $DBH->prepare($string);
        $sql->execute();
        // Unset data value to prevent retention
        unset ($kv);  
        }
```