# Save data in every LOOP

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I have a code in Javascript that looks like this.

```
for (var i in data){
            var trans_no = data[i]; //getting e row from table
            var transno = trans_no.transno
            var transdate = trans_no.transdate
            var dropno = trans_no.drop
            var cusname = trans_no.customername
            var shipto = trans_no.shipto
            var active = trans_no.active

            alert(transno + transdate  + dropno  + cusname  +  shipto  +  active);
            // window.location.href = "main.php?transno=" + transno; 
    }
```

What happens on that code is when I press a button my data from a source file is grabed and put it on the declarations above then display it in my alert or msgbox

and here is my php code on how to save data in SQL

```
<?php
        include('config.php');
        include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
        $db = ADONewConnection($dbdriver);
        $db->Connect($dsn, $username, $password);

        $sqlSync = "My SQL Query";
        $rsSync = $db->Execute($sqlSync);
        ?>
```

now lets say that my columns in my table is same name as inside in the alert().
        My question is that the script is encased in a loop. How can I save the data in SQL for every loop? I mean save the data that the loop made.
        TYSM

Answer (score 0):

store your data into an array then after loop completed, use `AJAX` call to pass the data to `php` for saving data.

Then with array you can insert multiple data with same query.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    ('a','b','c'),
    ('x','y','z'),
    ('q','w','e');
```

Comment: for multiple insert : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217566/how-to-loop-through-array-elements-to-create-multiple-insert-queries

Comment: I dont know how to do that sir :( since this is the only coding that i know please help me

Comment: and use ajax to send that array to your php file then Update your code